# PHP 7.3 Function create_function() deprecated from 5.6 update

Tags: php

I have recently upgraded a site im working on from PHP Version 5.6 to 7.3

The problem I am having is with a deprecated function in my wordpress functions.php

`add_filter('max_srcset_image_width', create_function('', 'return 1;'));`

How would i rewrite the above code for 7.3

I have already tried:

`add_filter('max_srcset_image_width', function('', 'return 1;'));`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use functions directly like closures.

```php
add_filter('max_srcset_image_width', function() { return 1; });
```

### Update:

Since PHP 7.4 you can use shorthand [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) and write it shorter.

```php
add_filter('max_srcset_image_width', fn() => 1);
```